# Maximal Interval of Definition for Solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to figure out the maximal interval of definition for solutions of some autonomous differential equation $\dot{x}=f(x)$. So, suppose we have some function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is locally Lipschitz continuous. We also know that $f(0)=0=f(1)$. We are also given that at time zero, $\dot{x}$ has a value in $[0,1]$. After trying it a few times, I'm stuck on whether this maximal interval is infinite i.e. $(-\infty,\infty)$ or if it's $(-\frac{x_0}{K},\frac{x_0}{K})$ where $K$ is such that $|f(x)| \leq K$, since I believe $f$ is bounded by our assumption about it being locally Lipschitz continuous.

However, I believe it's also true that $x(t_0)=0,x(t_1)=1$ and there exists some $t_1,t_0$ in the maximal interval such that $x'(t_0)=0,x'(t_1)=0$. Then this implies that $t_0,t_1$ give global max and min. Then if we denote our maximal interval as $I=(T_-,T_+)$, from the above information, we have $|x(t)|<\infty$, which implies $T_-,T_+$ are both not finite. This would lead to the maximal interval being $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Do either of these lines of thinking seem correct? Clearly they contradict one another because one interval is finite and the other is infinite.

Answer (score 1):

A solution of an autonomous first-order differential equation with $f$ locally Lipschitz is either constant, increasing or decreasing.  The only way for a solution to stop existing is to go off to $\pm \infty$.  If $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1)=0$, $x = 0$ and $x=1$ are solutions, and there are no other solutions that take the value $0$ or $1$.  Moreover if $0 \le x(0) \le 1$, the solution has to stay in the interval $[0,1]$, and thus  the maximal interval is $(-\infty, \infty)$.  If $x(0) < 0$ it is possible that the solution goes to $-\infty$ as $t$ approaches some finite value, and if $x(0) > 1$ it is possible that the solution goes to $+\infty$ as $t$ approaches some finite value.  Thus the maximal interval in these cases might be $(-\infty, T)$ or $(T, \infty)$.

For example, if $f(x) = x (1-x)$ there are solutions $x(t) = 1/(1 - \exp(t - T))$
for $t \in (-\infty, T)$ or $(T, \infty)$.

Note BTW that this is an example of $f$ which is locally (but not globally) Lipschitz and is not bounded.

Comment: So, in this problem $f(0)=0=f(1)$. If I'm understanding your explanation correctly, the only solutions are $x=0,x=1$. Given that $0 \leq x \leq 1$, our maximal interval has to in fact be $(-\infty,\infty)$? I also see from your comment that I was incorrect in saying that $f$ must be bounded because it is locally Lipschitz.

Comment: $x=0$ and $x=1$ aren't the only solutions, they are the only constant solutions. Yes, as I wrote, if $0 \le x(0) \le 1$, the maximal interval is $(-\infty, \infty)$.